# Select DIV base ond DIV name

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a DIV with the name "containerX". The X however can change in any number, depening on the input of the user that submits a value. Based on the number I want to show a certain DIV with values.

Is it possible to create a "if / else" statement in PHP that shows a certain div based on the name.

E.g.

if div name = containter7 then show the following

else if div name = container 8 then show the folloing

and on.

Have tried a lot so far, but can't seem to work it out.

Thnx

Comment: "Have tried a lot so far". Please post what you've tried.

Comment: not its not possible by php you can do this by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, assuming you're able to get a variable in PHP that represents the correct div name- There are a few different options, but this would probably be the best (works without too many changes).

Let's say you have the following divs-

```
<div id='div1'>Some div stuff(1)</div>
<div id='div2'>Some div stuff(2)</div>
<div id='div3'>Some div stuff(3)</div>
```

In the page's `head` tag, add a new style for hidden divs:

```
<style>
    div.hidden {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Then, change your divs to resemble the following:

```
<div id='div1' <?php  if(divName!="containter1") echo "class='hidden'" ?> >Some div stuff(1)</div>
<div id='div2' <?php  if(divName!="containter2") echo "class='hidden'" ?> >Some div stuff(2)</div>
<div id='div3' <?php  if(divName!="containter3") echo "class='hidden'" ?> >Some div stuff(3)</div>
```

That bit of PHP will set each div to the hidden class we made earlier, if the variable `divName` isn't equal to the right string.

This is by far not the most efficient code, but if you aren't too experienced in PHP (which forgive me for saying, but judging by the phrase `if div name = containter7`, I would have to assume you're new-ish to the language), then this will get the job done with minimal PHP involvement.